# How to unite 2 png images into 1 on client side using javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, png, sprite

So my client-side code recieves two PNG images. One of them is half-transparent. How can i overlay first image with the second one and convert it to third PNG file to use it later?
It like using them as layers to make 1 PNG image.
Is there any way to do it or any frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its *really* easy to do. You just need to use `drawImage` to draw the images onto the canvas in layers. As for saving, you use `toDataURL` which will return a base64 url for the image, which you can then do whatever with, open in a new window etc. However the images *must* come from the domain the code is running on in order to get the data url, or a security exception will be thrown. The jsfiddle example throws the security exception because Im pulling images from two random websites just as an example.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;
ctx.drawImage(image[0],0,0);
ctx.drawImage(image[1],0,0);

// will raise security exception if not from the same domain as the code.
var newImage = canvas.toDataURL();
​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/kuPPa/)**

Answer (score 0):

[**Pixastic**](http://www.pixastic.com/) is a JavaScript library which allows you to perform a variety of operations, filters and fancy effects on images using just a bit of JavaScript. To learn more about the library, see the [introduction page](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/).

The main focus of [**CamanJS**](http://camanjs.com/) is manipulating images using the HTML5 canvas and Javascript. It's a combination of a simple-to-use interface with advanced and efficient image/canvas editing techniques. It is also completely library independent and can be safely used next to jQuery, YUI, Scriptaculous, MooTools, etc.